# VS Code - enable autoClosingTags option in .vue files

Tags: vue.js, visual-studio-code

The html.autoClosingTags option in VS code lets me type '' - and voila, '' is now inserted with the cursor inside those two tags. But this only works in .html files.
I´m working on a vue project, and would like this feature to also be available in my .vue files (and any other files with html content actually).

Is this possible?

[image: VS code options]

Comment: Issue to keep an eye on (and show your support for) to provide this natively to the Vetur extension: https://github.com/vuejs/vetur/issues/565

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use the [Auto Close Tag](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.auto-close-tag) extension:

> This extension is enabled for other languages like XML, PHP, **Vue**, JavaScript, TypeScript, JSX, TSX and so on. It is configurable.
>
> ## Features
>
> - Automatically add closing tag when you type in the closing bracket of the opening tag
> - After closing tag is inserted, the cursor is between the opening and closing tag
> - Set the tag list that would not be auto closed
> - Automatically close self-closing tag
> - Support auto close tag as Sublime Text 3
> - Use Keyboard Shortcut or Command Palette to add close tag manually